# Корректно ли предложение?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Сотрудники обязаны принимать незамедлительные меры реагирования по поступившей информации" — корректно ли написано предложение?

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос, насколько я понимаю, в том, правильное ли управление: *меры по поступившей информации* или *реагирование по поступившей информации*. 'Меры по поступившей информации' - притянуто за уши. Можно сказать: *меры по улучшению...*, *меры по снижению...*. Но у вас уже есть *меры реагирования*. Глагол *реагировать* (а с ним и отглагольное существительное *реагирование*) управляет винительным падежом (*реагировать на что*) и творительным (спец. *реагировать с чем* в значении 'вступать в химическую реакцию'). Так что предложение ваше должно выглядеть следующим образом: "Сотрудники обязаны принимать незамедлительные меры реагирования на поступившую информацию".

Answer (score 1):

В 80-е говорить "по" было признаком принадлежности к высшей касте - торговцам. Например:"что у нас по трикотажу?" "Как дела на складе по резине?" Имелось ввиду, что вопрос задается об остатках.
Затем это взяли на вооружение органы внутренних дел. Они часто используют лексику своих подопечных, что, впрочем, наверное, имеет смысл и моральное оправдание.
Например: "что у нас по Всевышкину?" "Петров! У меня по вам вопросы будут!"
В 90-е это самое "по" использовалось в криминальных кругах, поскольку многие сотрудники из органов самым непосредственным образом стали "авторитетами".
Сейчас "авторитеты" говорят предельно грамотно. А феня перекочевала в Думу и стала языком топ-менеджеров.

Comment: Что-то не помню я такого признака принадлежности к "высшей касте". А ведь не ребёнком уже был - и в определенных кругах вертелся...

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, предложение получилось какое-то неудобоваримое. Нельзя ли сказать проще: "Сотрудники обязаны незамедлительно реагировать на поступившую информацию и принимать меры"? Или как-то так.